# Smooth CSS background image transition

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I have this little js script:
it works but the problem is when I hover buttons quickly the smooth transition effect doesn't work and it makes it very ugly when the img change suddenly.

thanks for helping.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#section2_list li");
  var div_img = document.getElementById('div_img');
    
  buttons[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    div_img.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/100)";          
  });
    
  buttons[1].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    div_img.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/100)";          
  });
```

```css
#div_img {
  width:  200px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.9s ease ;
 }
```

```html
<ul id="section2_list">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>

<div id="div_img">
</div>
```

Comment: If possible, try contributing a working snippet (stackoverflow has this tool in the text editor toolbar) so that it's easier for people to help you.

Comment: You have to either preload image to make transition smooth, or use image sprites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly transitioning the `background-image` property is not possible as [background-image is not an animatable property](http://w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties).

But you can stack two images and transition the top images' `opacity` to achieve the desired effect:

```js
var buttons     = document.querySelectorAll("#section2_list li");
var img_default = document.getElementById('img_default');
    
buttons[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  img_default.style.opacity = 0;
});
    
buttons[1].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  img_default.style.opacity = 1;
});
```

```css
#div_img {
  width:  200px;
  height: 100px;
}

#div_img img {
  position: absolute;
}

 #img_default {
   transition: all 0.9s ease ;
 }
```

```html
<ul id="section2_list">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>

<div id="div_img">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/100" />
  <img id="img_default" src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/100" />
</div>
```